# Can a GitHub codespace run indefinitely?

Tags: github, github-codespaces

I was wondering if we could configure a codespace to run indefinitely

and not time out when inactive

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/customizing-your-codespace/setting-your-timeout-period-for-github-codespaces) state that the maximum is 4 hours:

> Under "Default idle timeout", enter the time that you want, then click Save. The time must be between 5 minutes and 240 minutes (4 hours).